# TypeScript - Define a subset of type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

Say I have a type like so:

```
interface IAll {
  foo: boolean,
  bar: Function,
  baz: number
}
```

instead of manually defining all the possible subtypes of `IAll`, like so:

```
interface IAll1 {
  foo: boolean,
  bar: Function,
}

interface IAll2 {
  bar: Function,
  baz: number
}

interface IAll3 {
  foo: boolean,
}

interface IAll4 {
  foo: boolean,
}
```

...etc

and then doing

```
type IAll = IAll1 | IAll2 | IAll3 ... etc.
```

Is there a way for TypeScript to statically check whether an object is a subtype or subset of another?

This is useful for some cases where we combine several subtypes or subsets to form a full type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick). This will make all the properties in `IAll` optional:

```
type SubsetOfIAll = Partial<IAll>;
```

Comment: You can also use Partial for Types as well as interfaces e.g. ```type SubsetOfUser = Partial<User>```